# Microsoft Text Analytics Topic Detection - Internal error while executing BES operation

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I am getting an error when using Microsoft Topic Detection API [URL](https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/operations/c624adeab8494a8b9f798cd433da666c).

```
{{"status": "NotStarted","createdDateTime": "2016-07-22T06:09:06Z","operationType": "topics"}}

{{"status": "Running","createdDateTime": "2016-07-22T06:09:06Z","operationType": "topics"}}

{{"status": "Failed","createdDateTime": "2016-07-22T06:09:06Z","operationType": "topics","message": "Internal error while executing BES operation."}}
```

Any Ideas???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use same words/phrase for most of the documents.
use meaningful phrases. this will not give you an internal error.
I got same error before and i changed my documents.
Try this, hopefully this will solve your problem.